# Retain last selected value of a mat-select in Angular

Tags: angular

I am displaying the `mat-select` field under a collapsible `mat-card` my aim is retain the last selected value when I reopen the `mat-card`.
I have created the same scenario under this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zrerr-mlk7zs?file=app%2Fassocations%2Fassocations.component.ts

could anyone please tell me how can I achieve this.

Comment: use either `[formControl]` or `[ngModel]`, currently the select value is not bounded to any model variable.

Comment: @PankajParkar I have tried using [(ngModel)] but I am facing issue if I have same values   please check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zrerr-mlk7zs?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html

Comment: Check answer below, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngModel` to preserve the value. But make sure you have that `ngModel` binding as a part of each array element. Like consider adding property `selectedDropDownValue` on each element of collection.

```
[(ngModel)]="fields.selectedDropDownValue"
```

[**Forked Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zrerr-t2vnzr?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html)

Comment: thanks for your help could you please check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zrerr-bipe3p?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html the issue I am facing is that if I will select n/a from name card its respected associated field is displaying then if I will select n/a from address card its respected associated field is also displaying but if I will go back to name card its associated field is not displaying

Comment: you have to change line no.32 to `<app-assocations *ngIf="fields.selectedDropDownValue" [selectedValue]="fields.selectedDropDownValue"
   [fieldAssociations]=associations></app-assocations>`

check [update stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zrerr-t2vnzr?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html)